# Filling cells based in source range and a criteria

Tags: excel

I have a simple table containing a few products as:

| Item | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Fruit |
| Mango | Fruit |
| Chair | Furniture |

And a list of items and some values

| Store | Item | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Center | Banana | 1.50 |
| Beach | Banana | 2.50 |
| Center | Chair | 15.00 |
| Beach | Mango | 2.00 |

I would like to know how to dynamically add and fill a category in the second table (after the value column for example), fetching the data from the category table.

By dinamically I mean to use some programming function to extract the data to fill table 2 based on table 1. In SQL would be a JOIN. But I don't know how to handle in excel.

The idea is the final table should looks like

| Store | Item | Value | Category (dynamic) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Center | Banana | 1.50 | Fruit |
| Beach | Banana | 2.50 | Fruit |
| Center | Chair | 15.00 | Furniture |
| Beach | Mango | 2.00 | Fruit |
| Center | Water | 1.00 | NONE (or something like) |

Comment: Look for `INDEX/MATCH` ...

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by dynamic here?

Comment: added the description of dynamic.